# Vuex state not updating with mutation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, state, vuex

I'm trying to change the value of a state from false to true but it's not seeming to work. Below I will add my store, component that only gets the state, and the component that should update the state.

*//Store*

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        newComment: false,
        status: ''
    },
    mutations: {
        updateComments(state, payload) {
            state.newComment = payload;
        }
    }
});
```

**// Component that gets state**

```
<template>
    <div class="home">
        <h1>{{newComment}}</h1>
        <SelectedVideo v-bind:user="user" v-bind:video="videos[0]"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios';
    import SelectedVideo from '../components/SelectedVideo.component';
    axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;

    export default {
        name: 'Home',
        components: {
            SelectedVideo
        },
        data() {
            return {
                videos: [],
                user: null
            }
        },
        computed: {
            newComment() {
                return this.$store.state.newComment
            }
        },
```

**// Component I need to update state**

```
methods: {
                updateComments() {
                    this.$store.dispatch('updateComments', true);
                }
            },
            async createComment(comment, video, user) {
                try{
                    const res = await axios({
                        method: 'POST',
                        url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/comments/',
                        data: {
                            comment,
                            video,
                            user
                        }
                    });
                    if (res.data.status === 'success') {
                        console.log(res);
                        // location.reload(true);
                        this.updateComments();
                    }
                } catch(err) {
```

I'm successfully getting the state but updating seems to have no affect on state when I try to invoke the function to update.

Comment: `commit` not `dispatch`. `this.$store.commit('updateComments', true);`

Comment: I've tried that as well and nothing worked.

Comment: The correct syntax should be `this.$store.commit('updateComments', true);`. After changing that, can you add a `console.log(this.$store.state.newComment)` to see if the store is updated or not, right now I see no other errors from your code

Answer (score 0):

First make a getter for using state data.

```
getters:{
   get_newComment: state => state.newComment
}
```

Than implement this into your computed property.

```
computed: {
            newComment() {
                return this.$store.getters.get_newComment
            }
        }
```

After then use to "Commit" to commit some changes not "dispatch". Dispatch using for calling actions.

Comment: @metmet-pekcan , your getter does not actually do anything to the data. So instead you could just access that value directly. Same goes for the computed property. You might look into vuex's `mapState` to map a state value into your component's `data()`.

Comment: @Ronald yes you're right, here problem is not this but the best practice to use value from state Vuex says that use getters to do that. I did just fix this.

Comment: (mapState goes into the computed of course, not the data, oops)